# How to get YouTube videos in order of date uploaded

Tags: php, youtube

I have got a system for getting a number of videos from a YouTube channel, like so:

```
                <?php
                    $feedURL = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=UCMlW2qG20hcFYo06rcit4CQ&max-results=48&order=date';

                    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

                    $i = 0;
                    foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
                        $i++;

                        $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');

                        $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
                        $watch = $attrs['url'];
                        $vars;
                        parse_str( parse_url( $watch, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $vars );
                        $id = $vars['v'];

                        $check = $i % 3;

                        if($check == 1) {
                ?>
                        <div class="video-col tri-col-1 empty">
                            <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $id ?>/mqdefault.jpg" data-id="<?php echo $id ?>" class="video" />
                        </div>
                <?php
                        } else if($check == 2) {
                ?>
                        <div class="video-col tri-col-2 empty">
                            <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $id ?>/mqdefault.jpg" data-id="<?php echo $id ?>" class="video" />
                        </div>
                <?php
                        } else {
                ?>
                        <div class="video-col tri-col-3 empty">
                            <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $id ?>/mqdefault.jpg" data-id="<?php echo $id ?>" class="video" />
                        </div>
                <?php
                        }

                    }
                ?>
```

However, the videos are not provided in chronological order as I was expecting when I added the "&order=date" tag to the URL. How might I change my code to assure that the videos are provided in chronological order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the parameter is `orderby`, not `order`

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#orderbysp

> The orderby parameter, which is supported for video feeds and playlist feeds, specifies the method that will be used to order entries in the API response

Comment: Ah, thanks! I had been looking on here and a lot of posts mentioned order rather than orderby which was what was confusing me.